# Grant permissions to a SQL database role remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a short-term disaster recovery planning effort at my company, and we're planning on using replicated reporting servers as warm spares in case our primary transaction server dies.

Our web application can to write to that transaction server, but with only certain rights given by a SQL role. (webapplication)  I want to give us a way of updating this role that also updates the same role as it exists on other servers.  This way, if we fail over to another server, our webapplication role is reasonably close to the same, if not exactly the same.  (I'm not really worried about someone updating it directly)

So, I have a `MakeWebWriteable` procedure that should generate and execute some code like what is below.  Except, what's below clearly won't work.  I'm at a loss for how to reference the role and update it on a remote server.  I thought about using `exec (@sql) at [reporting\server]`, but I'm not sure how I would reference a certain database's role object within that.

```
grant insert, update, delete on dbo.TableName to webapplication
grant insert, update, delete on [reporting\server].DBName.dbo.TableName to [reporting\server].DBName.dbo.webapplication
```

How might I do this, or are there any better ideas? (i.e. replication)

---

**edit 1:** We generally write migrations as SQL scripts, commit those to SVN, and have our databases updated with a syncing script - sort of like what the process in RoR is, only without a model->SQL translation.  Ideally, we would just put a line at the end of a migration in which we added a table like so, if we want the table to be web-writeable.

```
-- Code to create NewTable...

if object_id('SetWebWriteable') is not null
    exec SetWebWriteable @tableName = 'NewTable'
```

This way, nothing happens on our developer machines, but in our test and production environments, the correct actions occur.  If the role can be replicated automatically, then naturally we wouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From what You are describing, You need SQLCMD utility. Connect to any server using the credentials it accepts (I usually use -E which represents windows authentication) and execute whatever scripts YOu need. If You are not trusted there, create an account with sufficient credentials.

The question is: What is the trigger of this script to execute? Do YOu execute it manually, or should it fire up automatically. In this case You are bound to write some code to achieve that (not very difficult though).

And You can leverage powershell built into SQL Server 2008 which can operate on objects on ANY server You can connect to (with your credentials). Look into that. It has a cmdlet Invoke-Sqlcmd which helps a TON.

luke

Comment: I've edited my question to address your questions.  We'd like to keep this within the confines a SQL script, basically, and this is triggered semi-manually with migration scripts.